# Parameter name changed on a library

Tags: android, android-library

I have created an android library. In my library there is an interface looks like this

```
public interface MyListener{
    void myFunction(String tag, String data);
}
```

I have pushed it on github and jitpack.io then I implement the library using gradle on my other project.
When I implement the listener to my activity, the function looks like this

```
void myFunction(String p0, String p1){ }
```

Why parameters name changed.?
Did I do something wrong on my library configuration?
Is this problem related to something called obfuscation?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the build.gradle file of your library and make sure the build types looks like this

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false // <<<< important
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```